# How have I activated my copy of Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, windows-activation

When I left my old job about four years ago, they let me keep my laptop, which was running Win7. A few months ago, this developed a boot problem so I completely wiped it and installed Win10 from scratch. However, I didn't want to *pay* for Win10 because I don't really need it. I have enough other devices that I don't actually need this laptop to work.

But I found this (and other sites), which said that I don't need to Activate Win10 to use it:

[https://www.howtogeek.com/244678/you-dont-need-a-product-key-to-install-and-use-windows-10/#:~:text=Microsoft%20allows%20anyone%20to%20download,10%20after%20you%20install%20it](https://www.howtogeek.com/244678/you-dont-need-a-product-key-to-install-and-use-windows-10/#:%7E:text=Microsoft%20allows%20anyone%20to%20download,10%20after%20you%20install%20it)

So I followed the instructions, which basically amount to clicking "I don't have a Product Key" every time the installation process asks for one, and I ended up with an inactivated version of Win10, which is what I expected. According to the page above, the restrictions are minor (e.g. unable to change the wallpaper) so I thought that would be ok.

However, I just noticed today that my Win10 ***is*** activated. My Activation status says:

> "Windows is activated with a digital licence linked to your Microsoft
> account".

However, I am positive I haven't paid for anything. I wouldn't have intentionally paid for a licence because, as I mentioned above, I don't really *need* another laptop. (I would have just not used the laptop, or found something else to install that was free.) But all the instructions I can find online say that in order to Activate using a digital license, you need to choose (and pay for) a license, unless you already have one.

So I'm confused about what is going on, and concerned that I might be inadvertantly using a licence that someone else has paid for. How can I find out what license I actually have, and who paid for it? (or have I somehow got a free licence?)

*(Note: I'd like to clarify that I am not trying to "get round" any Windows security here. If I have to pay, I'll either pay, or not use it. I'm not trying to do anything dodgy.)*

Comment: If the Windows 10 upgrade advisor was run on it, or it has a Windows 7 key stored in the BIOS area, it is possible that your Windows 7 key was used to "upgrade" you to Windows 10 via a digital entitlement.

Comment: I doubt you have "stolen" a key, simply your existing Windows 7 key has, one way or another, been used to activate your copy of Windows 10. Microsoft was (and still is I believe) pretty relaxed about upgrading old machines to Windows 10 and many suppliers like Dell put Windows keys in the system firmware for automated OS installations. (only comments because I can't say for 100% certain)

Comment: Chances are, your laptop originally came with Windows 10 or had Windows 10 installed on it as some point in the past.

Comment: @Mokubai Is there any way I can check this? Something like this occurred to me as a possibility, but I dismissed it a) because I'd wiped the disk (but if it's buried somewhere deeper than that, then maybe that would make sense), and b) I don't know how _that_ licence would be linked to my _personal_ Microsoft account (which is what I'm using now but not when it was a work PC)

Comment: Windows 10 automatically activated. If it’s not activating it’s possible you have the incorrect edition installed. I suspect the problem is that Windows 7 key wasn’t a retail key. Unless you can confirm what edition of Windows 7 you had installed we can’t really help you

Comment: @Daniel B I did install more than once. But there were no previous licensed editions of Win10. Having said that, I do have an MSDN account through work, and I _may_ have used a downloaded image from there (I can't remember), but I was _extremely_ careful not to use one of their license keys. Besides, my company uses an activation service, so if I'd inadvertently used one of those, it would say that rather than "a digital licence linked to your Microsoft account", right?

Comment: Ok, so I can find a product key using `wmic path SoftwareLicensingService get OA3xOriginalProductKey`. So it looks like I have a product key, but I don't know where this came from and I don't remember typing it in.

Comment: Nirsoft have a tool that can view your firmware tables and I believe you probably have a hardware Windows key stored in one of the MS* entries   https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/firmware_tables_view.html